# Joi data validation across multiple array fields

Tags: javascript, arrays, validation, joi

I already have an existing Joi validation that prevents two arrays being empty. I am trying to determine extending this further validation that prevents the value in being in both arrays. Is there is a way to check values in array that are in one but prevent them from being in another?

As an example this would be allowed:

```json
{
  "addUsers": ["michael@stack.com","nick@stack.com" ],
  "removeUsers": ["sara@stack.com"]
}
```

But this is not:

```json
{
  "addUsers": ["michael@stack.com","nick@stack.com" ],
  "removeUsers": ["michael@stack.com","sara@stack.com"]
}
```

and based on my existing validation, this is not:

```json
{
  "addUsers": [],
  "removeUsers": []
}
```

Here is a snippet of my existing validation:

```js
addUsers: Joi.when('removeUsers', {
  is: Joi.array().length(0),
  then: Joi.array().items(Joi.string().email())
    .unique()
    .required()
    .min(1)
    .messages({
      'array.unique': 'addUsers or removeUsers must contain a unique list of emails',
      'array.min': 'addUsers or removeUsers must contain at least 1 email',
      'any.required': 'addUsers or removeUsers must contain at least 1 email'
    })
    .example(['some.user@email.com', 'non.user@email.com']),
  otherwise: Joi.array().items(Joi.string().email())
    .unique()
    .example(['some.user@email.com', 'non.user@email.com'])
}),
removeUsers: Joi.array().items(Joi.string().email())
  .unique()
  .messages({
  'array.unique': 'addUsers or removeUsers must contain a unique list of emails'
  })
  .example(['some.other.user@email.com'])
```

Maybe a custom validator but I am not sure if that would work either.
Any guidance is appreciated.